# C# SQLite Database Update Command Not Updating Database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, command

So I'm developing a Music Player for my final Year project. It has a SQlite Database to store Album and Track information. The code below is an update function to allow the track's file path to be updated if it is moved. However it while it returns no errors, the file path in the database fails to update. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

```
private void updateTrackFilePath(int albumid, String name, String filepath)
    {
        sql = "update tracks set filepath = (@filepath) where trackid = (@trackid)";
        mCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, mdbConnection);
        mCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filepath", filepath);
        mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trackid", getTrackId(name, albumid));
        mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: what is your mdbConnection? may be its pointing to another DB

Comment: Since `mCommand` is not created there it looks like you are reusing it?  Thats a bad idea because it could have 3 or 5 or N parameters left over from the last use.  Create, use and dispose of them as needed (same with Connection objects).  Also `AddWithValue` is a bad idea especially with SQLIte

Comment: What is `name`? `albumid`? `filepath`? `getTrackId(name, albumid)`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a syntax error in the generated SQL query string after the params are included. If you put a breakpoint at the ExecuteNonQuery method and obtain the final query string, you can run it directly in a management tool (http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) and see if there are syntax errors that cause an unexpected result.